# Revealing 1 random letter of a word doesnt work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create an app where the user has to guess the company name of an icon. Everything works fine but I want to have a button that prints a hint for the user. I want to print 1 random letter of the companys name. But the company name and the length of the name changes because of the different levels.
So I thought I had to get the length of the companys name and then pick a random number of 0-companyname.
Then I could use substring to chose 1 random letter of the companyname.
But it doesnt work. Here the important parts my code:

```
Import java.util.Random;

int Laenge;
int BuchstabenPosition;
int DanachBuchstabenPosition;
Random r = new Random();
  
Laenge = companyName.length();
BuchstabenPosition = r.nextInt(Laenge);
DanachBuchstabenPosition = BuchstabenPosition += 1;
tvHint.setText("Ein Buchstabe: " + companyName.substring(BuchstabenPosition,DanachBuchstabenPosition));
```

When I run the app and click on the hint button, it only shows "Ein Buchstabe: ".
I hope u understand what I want to do but here an example:

Level 1: Icon of YouTube, user doesnt have a clue of the company name, clicks hint button, a random letter of the word reveals, user now knows the name of the company and get to level 2.

Level 2: Icon of Stackoverflow, user doesnt have a clue of the company name, clicks hint button, a random letter of the word reveals.

If every company name would have the same length I could just make for example:

```
  int BuchstabenPosition;
  int DanachBuchstabenPosition;
  Random r = new Random();

  BuchstabenPosition = r.nextInt(8);
  DanachBuchstabenPosition = BuchstabenPosition += 1;
  tvHint.setText("Ein Buchstabe: " + companyName.substring(BuchstabenPosition,DanachBuchstabenPosition));
```

right?
But the companyname length changes.

Comment: You say it doesn't work. What exactly do you mean? What happens, and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Remove the `+` symbol from this line `DanachBuchstabenPosition = BuchstabenPosition += 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
DanachBuchstabenPosition = BuchstabenPosition += 1;
```

Will first increment `BuchstabenPosition`, then assign `DanachBuchstabenPosition` to be the value of `BuchstabenPosition`. So, `BuchstabenPosition` and `DanachBuchstabenPosition` are the same integer. The call to [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) will then return the empty string `""`.

Instead assign `DanachBuchstabenPosition` as this:

```
DanachBuchstabenPosition = BuchstabenPosition + 1;
```

So that it is 1 greater than `BuchstabenPosition`.

Also, consider using [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) instead, which is closer to what the logic of your code requires.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
String name = "Oracle";

Random random = new Random();
int index = random.nextInt(name.length());
        
char randomChar = name.charAt(index);
        
System.out.println("Index:" + index + " Letter:" + randomChar);
```